# Need to correct the code (Add a group to AD)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Creat a new Domainlocal group "sale_users_01" under OU sale->sale02  and put it member of "test_user_01" using cmd!

```
New-ADGroup -Path “cn=sale,ou=sale02,DC=nett,DC=dd,DC=nett,DC=com” -Name “Sale_users_01” -GroupType 'Security' -GroupScope 'DomainLocal' -member $("test_user_01")
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? Be specific

Answer (score 1):

Show some effort. You can't just invent your own syntax, read the documentation at [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617258.aspx)

`-Path` is the path for the container you want to create the group in, not the DN.

`-Member` doesn't exist in `New-ADGroup`. Adding members is done with `Add-ADGroupMember`.

Try something like:

```
$group = New-ADGroup -SamAccountName "sale" -Path “ou=sale02,DC=nett,DC=dd,DC=nett,DC=com” -Name “Sale_users_01” -GroupType 'Security' -GroupScope 'DomainLocal'
$group | Add-ADGroupMember -Members "test_user_01"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry for little misleading variables.Test_user_01 and Sale_user_01 both is a group. Will this line: $group | Add-ADGroupMember -Members "test_user_01" add test_user_01 member of sale_user_01?

Comment: I just tried the code. it's seems like there is some syntax error! I could't figure it out! 

Possible error can be on grouptype/groupscop!

How you can change the code, If you want to add one more parent OU (Eg : MotherOU -childOU - ChildOU) ?

Comment: ? I haven't tried the code, but it should work. Are you trying to create an OU or change the parent ou to create the group in? If it's the latter, simply add `OU=ChildOU,` in front of `ou=sale02,....`